# If L1 ∪ L2 and L1 are regular, is L2 also regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

This is a problem in a theory of computation book that's stumping me:

> Suppose that we know that $L_1 ∪ L_2$ and $L_1$ are regular. Can we conclude that $L_2$ is 
>   regular? Explain.

At first, I thought I could build the NFA that is the union of two DFAs, one which accepts $L_1$, and one which we don't know about.  Then lambda transition over to the $L_1$ DFA.  Then, the union would be regular, but we wouldn't be able to conclude anything about the $L_2$ DFA.

I think my reasoning is poor though.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: make $L_1$ big. Hint 2: make $L_1 \subseteq L_2$.

Comment: [Similar question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11592/prove-that-l-1-is-regular-if-l-2-l-1l-2-l-2l-1-are-regular).

Comment: You tell me. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove a language is regular?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/how-to-prove-a-language-is-regular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since $\Sigma^* \cup L$ and $\Sigma^*$ are regular languages, for any $L$ and there are non-regular languages, we cannot conclude anything about $L$.